# XAMPP localhost returns object not found after installing Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, laravel-4

After much faffing about I got laravel to work with XAMPP. However, I can't seem to access directories in the htdocs folder via localhost now. Attempt to access a file returns `Object not found!` along with `The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.`

The changes I made to get laravel working seems like a blur now. The only thing I remember doing is editing the `hosts` file to enable the virtual host to work by adding `127.0.0.1       laravel.dev` in the hosts file (using a mac btw). I also added a virtual host to the httpd-vhost.conf file.

I did undo the above changes but it didn't make a difference.

Any thoughts on whats gone wrong?

Thanks.

**Dispelling Confusion**
Just thought I'd clarify what my experience is. Before installing **laravel 4** I could access all my projects with `localhost/someProjectName` but now it fails.

I'm trying to identify what change caused this behaviour. Btw, I have no problems accessing my laravel project (my mapping allows me access to it via `laravel.dev`)

Comment: @asipiringCodeArtisan I am also experiencing the exact same error. I installed Laravel using composer and served the Laravel driven site using `artisan serve`. Ever since this my existing (non Laravel) projects no longer work as intended in vhosts. Did you end up fixing this?

Comment: @nickspiel: I suspect this has something to do with the virtual host config. I don't have the solution, I just know where the problem lies.

Comment: Yeah you were correct, it turns out i had a typo in a path for mys log files. - Schoolboy error.

Answer (score 17):

Look into your `/etc/httpd.conf` file and see if you have Virtual hosts activated.

If so, check your `etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file. You might have set up a VirtualHost already.

EDIT: I have found that once you turn on Virtual Hosts, XAMPP needs a default VirtualHost for your basic htdocs files

Try adding a default VirtualHost (at the bottom of the file) like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs"
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
AllowOverride All
Order Allow,Deny
Allow From All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You should maybe try explaining what you're suggesting doing here, rather d¨than simply giving instructions - this way the user who asked the question can also learn :)

Comment: I need to add this line: "Require all granted" after
"Allow from all"

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like it is a problem with the way your directories are configured. Be sure to create a Virtual Host (if you're using Apache) that points to the **public** folder within your application directory.

For example, if your Laravel project is under /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/Laravel then set up a Virtual Host like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/Laravel/public

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Additionaly, if you're working with PHP >= 5.4, SSH into the application folder and run

```
./artisan serve
```

(Be sure that your PHP executable is in your PATH variable). Then go localhost:8000 and you should have your application running. 
Running this command runs the PHP built-in webserver and saves you the trouble of configuring virtual hosts.

Answer (score 2):

In your Apache's http.conf, find the `DocumentRoot` line and add the subdirectory `/public` on the end.

Once that is done and you've restarted Apache, you'll be able to access everything which is contained within your `htdocs/public` folder (including subdirectories of that folder), along with any routes you've defined in Laravel.

Laravel is designed to be set up this way as to protect the code and files by not having them in the folder which is served out to the web.

Comment: hey there, I'm actually trying to access my non-laravel driven projects. I can access my laravel project successfully but other seem to fail.

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue and found that there are miss configuration in vhost. So that's are correct configuration.

in `etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/laravel-master/public"
    ServerName laravel.local
    ErrorLog "logs/laravel-master-error.log"
     <Directory D:/xampp/htdocs/laravel-master/public>  
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In the hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 laravel.local
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're running L4 or L3. However, launch CLI and

> $ cd ./path/to/project

Then for L4:

```
$ php artisan serve
```

For L3:

```
$ php -S localhost:8000 -t public
```

Now you can go to `localhost:8000` and see your application.

Answer (score 1):

You're having problem because the object really doesn't exist in your `htdocs` directory. You don't have to append `xampp` after `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` because `xampp` will treat it as an object or a folder under `htdocs`.

if you want to access your blog, make sure you have a blog folder under `htdocs` and put in your URL `localhost/blog`