# routing in laravel3 not working properly

Tags: php, laravel

I am new bee in Laravel. I have set up Laravel  by help of this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/building-web-applications-from-scratch-with-laravel/). I have set virtual host, on my virtual host I wrote this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ranjitalaravel.com
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/laravel4/public"
   <Directory "/var/www/html/laravel4/public"> 
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In my host file i.e. /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 ranjitalaravel.com
```

When I type the http://ranjitalaravel.com/ on my browser all list of file inside my laravel directory is showing. But when I type home after it it shows me "The requested URL /home was not found on this server.". I have write this code in route.php inside application folder.

```
Route::any('home', function()
{
    return View::make('home.index');
});
```

Comment: Did you restart Apache after adding your virtual host config?

Comment: You said laravel3 in your question but the directory says laravel4. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@some_server
    DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs/some_server"
    ServerName some_server
    ServerAlias some_server
    ErrorLog "logs/some_server.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/some_server.localhost-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

this works fine to me, hope helps you

Comment: I have tried this.But still not working. 404 Not found is showing when I am going to The requested URL /home

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ranjitalaravel.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel4/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/laravel4/public/>
            Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

are you using symlinks?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using VirtualHosts which can get nasty from time to time why not use PHP 5.4 inbuilt development server.

Here's how [XAMPP localhost returns object not found after installing Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129612/xampp-localhost-returns-object-not-found-after-installing-laravel)